Azure Devops Variable Template Expression
global.yml
parameters:
- name: environment
  type: string

variables:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'd') }}:
  - name: location
    value: westeurope
- ${{ elseif eq(parameters.environment, 't') }}:
  - name: location
    value: westeurope
- ${{ elseif eq(parameters.environment, 'i') }}:
  - name: location
    value: northcentralus
- ${{ else }}:
  - name: location
    value: ${{parameters.environment}}

build.yml
variables:
## Variables group from pipelines library
- group: SOME-GROUP
### Template vars
- template: templates/vars/global.yml
  parameters:
    environment: $(env)

$(env) is the variable set at Azure Pipeline UI.
The global.yml file serves as the template for loading variables, while the build.yml file is the build pipeline that utilizes global.yml. However, I'm encountering an issue where the template expressions in global.yml are not functioning as expected. Specifically, the location variable is set to 'd' despite the parameters.environment being set to 'd'. It always goes to else condition. I have already invested a considerable amount of time attempting to resolve this issue without success. Could someone please assist in determining if this is a solvable problem?

Expressions in ${{}} are evaluated at template compilation time, which is before runtime variable exist.

@DanielMann How can I load the variables then dynamically?
